# Link single material from another object

Tags: materials

Is there a way in Blender to link only one material from another object? For example, if I have Object1 with materials A and B, and Object2 with materials C and D, what if I want to add A to Object2, but not B, and also retain C and D? Link Materials operation seems to just replace all materials slots with those from Object1, while Copy Material creates a copy and not a link.

Comment: Create a new slot for object 2 (under the material list click on New) and select material A for this slot?

Comment: Gee, I have not noticed that you can also select it right there! Thanks, that answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new slot for object 2 (under the material list click on *New*) and select material A for this slot:

[image]

Or in the *Shader Editor*:

[image]